# Google Spreadsheets Script not Working if Values are Entered Quickly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have written a following script for my Google Spreadsheet:

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var column = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var dat = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue()+"";
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5:30", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var editor = doc.getViewers();
  var temp = e.oldValue;
  if(dat=="")
  {
    dat = "0.0"
  }
  if((column == 4 || column == 5) && temp != null)
  {
    cell.setComment("Value changed from ₹"+ (temp) + " to ₹" + dat + " on " + curDate);
  }

}
```

I use this code to insert a comment when a value is changed in the column D or E. I am using this script since a month and the code works perfect. But I recently noted an issue with it.

1. If I enter values quickly in several cells, for example, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6 etc., the code is not executed for all cells and comment is added to some random cells only. It is executed as expected only when I keep minimum interval of 1 second between entering records.
2. If I delete values from multiple cells at once, the code is not executed for any cell.

Thanks for reading the code.

Comment: Looks like you're getting stuck either at runtime of the script or at the fact that an edit doesn't always do single cells (You can edit a range). try using Chemiadel's answer to find a way to activate the event properly when the edited part is a group of cells, not a single one.

check this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to see what the event actually brings so you don't have to repeat work.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first issue, I was able to reproduce the problem using the following script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var destination = e.range.offset(0,1);
  if(e.value){ // Do this when editing a range having only one cell
    destination.setValue(e.value);
  } else { // Do this when editing a range having multiple cells
    destination.setValues(e.range.getValues());
  }
}
```

This should be reported to Google by using the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%20status:open&p=1).

Regarding the second issue, getActiveCell returns only the active cell and it looks that the entire range is required. It's worth to note that e.oldValue returns null when a range with more than one cell is being edited.

The following is an alternative version of your script that works both for single cell editing as multiple cell editing at once:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var column = e.range.getColumn();
  if(column == 4 || column == 5){
    if(e.range.getNumRows() == 1 && e.oldValue != undefined){
      e.range.setNote("Old value: " + ((e.oldValue)?e.oldValue:"0.0") + "| New value: " + ((e.value)?e.value:"0.0"));
    } 
    if(e.range.getNumRows() > 1){
      var values = e.range.getValues();
      for(var i = 1;i<=e.range.getNumRows();i++){
        e.range.getCell(i,1).setNote("Old value: Not available | New value: " +  ((values[i-1][0])?(values[i-1][0]):"0.0"));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: setComment is not included on the official Google Apps Script reference for the Spreadsheet Service.

Related Issues

- [onEdit Trigger not firing when slow network](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67930342)

Answer (score 0):

i get this from GAS Guide about triggers may helps you

add a comment to edited range with this way :

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```